# kendo-knockout: change options set (with data source) in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo-knockout library. A grid is bound to an observable options set. This observable is initialized with options set "heroes" containing an observable data array and a columns definition.

After button click the observable is filled with another options set "cars" with another observable data array and another columns definition.

But the grid still displays the heroes instead of cars.

The code situation is very easy:

```js
<button id="btn" data-bind="click: changeDataSource">change data source</button>
<div id="grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: heroOptions"></div>

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    // first data source
    self.heroes = ko.observableArray([ { name: ko.observable("spiderman"), age: ko.observable("29") }, { name: ko.observable("batman"), age: ko.observable("55") }, { name: ko.observable("hulk"), age: ko.observable("40") } ]);

    // second data source
    self.cars = ko.observableArray([ { model: ko.observable("Z8"), manufacturer: ko.observable("BMW"), country: ko.observable("Germany") }, { model: ko.observable("911"), manufacturer: ko.observable("Porsche"), country: ko.observable("Germany") }, { model: ko.observable("S600 AMG"), manufacturer: ko.observable("Mercedes"), country: ko.observable("Germany") } ]);

    // observable for options (where the grid is bound to)
    self.options = ko.observable();

    // options for first data source
    self.heroOptions = { data: self.heroes, columns: [{title:'Hero',field:'name'},{title:'Age',field:'age'}] };

    // options for second data source
    self.carOptions = { data: self.cars, columns: [{title:'Car',field:'model'}, {title:'Producer',field:'manufacturer'},{title:'Country',field:'country'}] };

    // set initial grid options
    self.options(self.heroOptions);

    // method to bind grid to second data source
    self.changeDataSource = function () {
        self.options(self.carOptions);
    };
}

var model = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

The problem: 
The method changeDataSource() fills self.options with self.carOptions but the grid wont be refreshed.

I think I'll need a rebind/refresh or something else.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harald_betzler/5qu6ud8g/1/

Comment: i'm not familiar with ko but if you could get the reference to kendo grid widget instance try gridWidgetInstance.refresh(). On jquery i used $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();

Comment: @machun: Thank you. I tried this idea - but no success. It really refreshs, but obviously the "old" data source.